# How to connect five different tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

How to connect in SQL whhen three connect to the main one, and the fourth only connects to one of the smaller tables.

I know inner joins for all are not the answer, but I have drawn it out thinking visually would help, and have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: If you list the tables and the columns, along with details about how they are related to each other (which columns connect them), then we write a query. Also useful would be the cardinality (whether they are one-to-one or one-to-many relationships).

Comment: Always proofread your question before posting and try to always provide some Visual AID of your tables so we can better visualize what you are trying to do and offer some help

Answer (score 0):

Without sufficient information, this cannot be answered properly. But if you want to connect 5 different tables together, then all 5 tables must have some sort of relation that exist between them. Think of how you could actually link them by finding what is common between the tables. That is called RELATION.